# How to ouput 2 dimensional Array in Google Script and send it by email so it will display correctly?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Thanks in advance for anyone could help.

I cannot figure out how to code the google script to output 2-dimensional arrays(which grabbed it from google excel sheet), send it via email and display in outlook in the correct way. Grabbed some simple coding from the web and it only works when send to Gmail, not Outlook, it seems like outlook doesn't display all the HTML code correctly.

The array is below. I am trying to display them as :

Name (TAB) Amount

ABBI (TAB) 625

Cindy(TAB) 625 and so on.

Thanks....

```
[[NAME, AMOUNT], [ABBI, 625.0], [Cindy, 625.0], [LANI, 738.04], [Juan, 732.65], [DEAN, 398.24], [TOM, 0.0], [LIAM, 849.52], [Summer, 0.0]]
```

}

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. Will you achieve your goal using Google Apps Script? 2. Can you provide your script for replicating your current issue? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: I try not to put the codes on the question because my scripts are all over the place and it doesn't make sense if I just paste part of it.

Comment: I will get a bad rating because I am not helping other people, which it's not true, I am just not good of putting the good question and providing a good conntent

Comment: What personal information that I have to remove?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand that you cannot provide your script. About `What personal information that I have to remove?`, I cannot answer because I cannot understand about your situation. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook does not support modern div options.

```js
    var arr = [['NAME', 'AMOUNT'], ['ABBI', 625.0], ['Cindy', 625.0], ['LANI', 738.04], ['Juan', 732.65], ['DEAN', 398.24], ['TOM', 0.0], ['LIAM', 849.52], ['Summer', 0.0]];
    var html = "<table border='0'>"
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
     html+= "<tr><td>"+arr[i][0]+" &emsp; "+arr[i][1]+"</td></tr>";
    }
    html += "</table>"
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks So much, I will give this a try.